# Convert column where values type are string to numeric

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science

I have this DF (gdp_g20) with information of GDP, first line example below:

> Country Name   Country Code    Indicator Name  Indicator Code  2014
> Argentina  ARG GDP (current US$)   NY.GDP.MKTP.CD  $526,320,000,000.00

I want to plot it but as the value types of column '2014' are string, it's not possible.

So anyone know how to convert gdp_g20['2014'] to numeric data? I've seen some posts but none of them worked.

Thanks in advance.

I tried removing the $ sign and convert with to_numeric, as below:

`gdp_g20['2014'] = gdp_g20['2014'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('$', ''))`
`gdp_g20['2014'] = pd.to_numeric(gdp_g20['2014'])`

But then I got the error:

"Unable to parse string " 526,320,000,000.00 " at position 0"

Comment: Removing the dollar sign should allow any other method to recast the datatype as numerical data i think.

Comment: I've tried that but got an error. Edited the post so you can see. May you can have an other idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `$` and get rid of the `,`, this should do it.

```py
gdp_g20['2014'] = data['2014'].str[1:].str.replace(',','').astype(float)
```

Comment: Thanks! did it in a different way but it worked.                                                                                              
         `gdp_g20['2014'] = gdp_g20['2014'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('$', '').replace(',', ''))`
          `gdp_g20['2014'] = pd.to_numeric(gdp_g20['2014'])`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you were on the right track you just need to remove the "," too

Adding another line to your code like this works

```
gdp_g20["2014"] = gdp_g20['2014'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('$', ''))
gdp_g20["2014"] = gdp_g20['2014'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(',', ''))
gdp_g20['2014'] = pd.to_numeric(gdp_g20['2014'])
```